# Change DMARC Report frequency

Tags: gmail, g-suite, dkim, dmarc

My current record look like this:

> v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:varun1@varunagw.com; ruf=mailto:Varun2@VarunAgw.com; pct=100; ri=604800

Still for some reason, I receive E-Mail from Google everyday instead of 7 days (604800 seconds) which is very annoying. Is it possibly to make Google send me weekly reports?

Comment: If this is for varunagw.com then `dig TXT varunagw.com` does not return this for me. I get the following: `"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:spf.smtp2go.com ~all" "google-site-verification=BM-IovA8_SeXDTKerRmMnPMtR_BGpSqs1QDxjZLH-mg"`

Comment: @ojs It is SPF record. `dig TXT _dmarc.varunagw.com` shows correct DMARC record.

Comment: According to [instructions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466563?hl=en&ref_topic=2759254) then they say they don't support the *ruf* tag but they make no mention of *ri* tag. Perhaps they don't support it either and someone more knowledgeable about gmail could answer that.

Answer (score 4):

From DMARC [RFC 7489, 6.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-6.3), emphasis is mine:

> `ri`: Interval requested between aggregate reports (plain-text 32-bit
> unsigned integer; OPTIONAL; default is `86400`). Indicates a request
> to Receivers to generate aggregate reports separated by **no more than
> the requested number of seconds**. DMARC implementations MUST be able
> to provide daily reports and SHOULD be able to provide hourly reports
> when requested. However, **anything other than a daily report is
> understood to be accommodated on a best- effort basis**.

This suggests that the normal interval for reports is 24 hours and a **shorter** period can be requested, but is optional. It mentions nothing about a longer interval, and a longer interval would also mean the receiving mail system should cache the data for extended periods.

This is why it's perfectly fine that Gmail has chosen to simplify this and send daily reports. A hint of this can be found at G Suite Admin Help [About DMARC](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580?hl=en):

> DMARC reports
>
> You can set up DMARC to send you a daily report from all participating
> email providers.

This makes me believe Gmail doesn't care about the `ri` tag at all.

Comment: That's unfortunate.

Comment: You should have automatic handling for the xml reports, anyway. It doesn't really matter whether the tool gathers data on daily or weekly basis.

Comment: It's for my personal blog (not some organization). I don't want to over-complicate stuff further.

Answer (score -1):

Google should respect the ri (Reporting interval) but DMARC is still new.
you can remove the rua and ruf tags (as they are optional) so you don't receive reports or you can create a different email for reports to be sent to.